# How to make smooth animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make smooth animation of appearing and disappearing a block of text. It appears smoothly but disappears very fast. How can I make it smooth?

```js
const answer = document.querySelector(".answer-to-questions");

const plusSign = document.querySelector(".plus-sign");

const questionHeader = document.querySelector(".question-header");

// plusSign.forEach((item)=>{

//     // item.addEventListener('click',()=>{
//     //     answer.classList.toggle('display');
//     // })

// })

plusSign.addEventListener("click", () => {
  answer.classList.toggle("display");
  questionHeader.classList.add("add-padding");

  if (answer.classList.contains("display")) {
    plusSign.src = "../images/plus-close.svg";
  } else {
    plusSign.src = "../images/plus.svg";
    questionHeader.classList.remove("add-padding");
  }
});
```

```css
.question-header>* {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.question-header>* {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.question-header {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.question-header.add-padding {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.add-padding {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.question-header h3 {
  width: 701px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #101828;
}

.plus-sign {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer-to-questions.display {
  max-width: 630px;
  position: sticky;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(5%);
}

.answer-to-questions {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="question-header">
    <h3>Have you built an App similar to mine?</h3>
    <img class="plus-sign" src="./images/plus.svg" alt="" srcset="" />

    <div class="answer-to-questions">
      <p>
        Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce,
        the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the link to code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-monad-se1m22?file=/index.html:0-1010 .

Hopefully, I made this clear. Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: why have you split your code between 3 separate snippets that do nothing?

Comment: in general, for a `transition` to be effective, it must exist on the element before the property that is being transitioned is changed .... at a guess, you're adding a class that has both the transition property and the transitioned property

Comment: Oh okay, and how do I smoothly change image? Thank you!

Comment: not sure, as I can't make heads nor tails of your code ... but have the transition property existing on the element before you transition will make the transition work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with setting contents's `max-height: 0;` when collapsed, and `max-height: x;` when expanded

> By `x` in `max-height: x;`, I mean the content's height that you can get it with js

> PS: Because I didn't have access to your `./images/plus.svg`, replaced it with something else

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".question-header");

[...items].forEach((item) => {
  const plusSign = item.querySelector(".plus-sign");
  const answer = item.querySelector(".answer-to-questions");
  const elemnts = [plusSign, item, answer];

  plusSign.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (answer.style.maxHeight) {
      answer.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      answer.style.maxHeight = answer.scrollHeight + "px";
    }

    elemnts.forEach((e) => {
      e.classList.toggle("expanded");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #354259;
}

.question-header {
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #c7c7c7;
}

.question-header,
.question-header * {
  transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}

.question-header.expanded {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

.title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: inherit;
}

.title h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.plus-sign {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  --thickness: 1.5px;
  width: 15px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-color: transparent;
  background: conic-gradient( from 90deg at var(--thickness) var(--thickness), transparent 90deg, #000 0) calc(100% + var(--thickness) / 2) calc(100% + var(--thickness) / 2) / calc(50% + var(--thickness)) calc(50% + var(--thickness));
}

.plus-sign.expanded {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: conic-gradient( from 0deg at var(--thickness) var(--thickness), transparent 180deg, #000 0) calc(100% + var(--thickness) / 2) calc(100% + var(--thickness) / 2) / calc(50% + var(--thickness)) calc(50% + var(--thickness));
}

.answer-to-questions {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.answer-to-questions.expanded {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="question-header">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Have you built an App similar to mine?</h3>
    <span class="plus-sign"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-to-questions">
    <p>
      Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce,
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-header">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Have you built an App similar to mine?</h3>
    <span class="plus-sign"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-to-questions">
    <p>
      Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce,
      the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more.
      Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like
      E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and
      many more.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-header">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Have you built an App similar to mine?</h3>
    <span class="plus-sign"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-to-questions">
    <p>
      Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce, the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more. Since 2010, we've successfully implemented 160+ projects for industries like E-Commerce,
      the Internet of Things, Digital music distribution, E-Learning, and many more.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```